# Extension/Constructor on a Component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, controller-extension, constructor

I have a Component inside of a Visualforce Page. I am not sure if this line of connection is causing a break but my issue is with my constructor. It is not taking in the params I am passing:

Page:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Credit_Review__c" action="{!checkValidVersion}" extensions="CreditreViewScreenController,CreditReportRemoting,sendToWebService2,RecommendationPanelController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <c:CreditReviewScreenRelatedDealsTab creditReviewObj="{!creditReview}" table="{!TableValue}" associatedContactsObjMap="{!ConsumerCreditSummaryMap}" associatedContactsObj="{!associatedContactList}" CreditSummaryObj1="{!CreditSummaryObj1}"/>
```

Component:

```
<apex:component id="CreditReviewScreenRelatedDealsTab" controller="IDAnalyticsController" extensions="oliviaTestClass" allowDML="true">
```

Extension:

```
public class oliviaTestClass {

    public oliviaTestClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}
}
```

I have tried passing in a `StandardSetContoller`, extending oliviaTestClass with  `extends IDAnalyticsController`, assigning variable controller a value.... but I continue to get error: `Error:(1, 1) Unknown constructor 'oliviaTestClass.oliviaTestClass(IDAnalyticsController controller)'` What am I missing with constructors and class extensions? I have followed the documentation below with no success.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm

*note: I did not include IDAnalyticsController for it is over 1000 lines long

Comment: why are using custom controller extension?

Comment: Have you tried a no-args constructor i.e. `public oliviaTestClass()` or no constructor?

Comment: Just use custom controller

Comment: @SantanuBoral I wanted to separate the logic from the IDAnalyticsController. It is two different projects so I was hoping to keep it clean. I can add to the IDAnalyticsController if needed.

Comment: @KeithC I have tried to not pass in any args and I get the typical error message:  `Error:(1, 1) Unknown constructor 'oliviaTestClass.oliviaTestClass(IDAnalyticsController controller)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the constructor argument is often an `ApexPages.StandardController` because an SObject type is specified in the `controller` argument, where you specify a specific class as the `controller` argument it is that class name that needs to be the argument to the extension class constructor:

```
public class oliviaTestClass {
    private IDAnalyticsController ac;
    public oliviaTestClass(IDAnalyticsController ac) {
        this.ac = ac;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: ahhh this makes so much sense. IDAnalyticsController is not a standardcontroller. Thank you!